# Draw a Lorenz curve in R

Tags: r

I would like to draw a [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve) and calculate a Gini index with the objective to determine how much parasites does the top 20% most infected hosts support.

Here is my data set:

Number of parasites per host:

```
parasites = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Number of hosts associated with each number of parasites given above:

```
hosts = c(18,20,28,19,16,10,3,1,0,0,0)
```

To represent the Lorenz curve:

I manually calculated the cumulative percentage of parasites and hosts:

```
cumul_parasites <- cumsum(parasites)/max(cumsum(parasites))
cumul_hosts <- cumsum(hosts)/max(cumsum(hosts))
plot(cumul_hosts, cumul_parasites, type= "l")
```

[image]

I also tested the function `Lc` (package `ineq`):

```
Lc.p <- Lc(parasites,n=hosts)
plot(Lc.p)
```

[image]

Why are the two curves (manual and function `Lc`) different ?

Comment: I think it's a sorting difference. Yours is sorted by increasing `parasites`, and the `ineq` version seems to be sorted by increasing `hosts`.

Comment: Should I use `Lc(hosts,n=parasites)` instead of `Lc(parasites,n=hosts)` ?

Comment: You could certainly try it! You don't need my permission for that.

Comment: It really depends whether you want to change your graph to match the Lorenz curve or change the Lorenze curve to match your graph. For option 1, I think you need to sort your data differently.

Comment: I think that the two curves are different because of the code line `x <- n * x` in the function `Lc`.

Comment: You might also need to prepend 0's to each of your vectors within your function. Presumably with 18 hosts having 0 parasites, your curve should start from 0, 0 and be flat, like the one produced by `Lc`. Instead your curve starts increasing immediately and the x-axis doesn't extend to 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2 graphs are different because when you calculate the cumulative precentage (the degree) you must multiply it with the frequency.

The right solution would be:

```
parasites = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
hosts = c(18,20,28,19,16,10,3,1,0,0,0)
cumul_parasites <- cumsum(parasites*hosts)/max(cumsum(parasites*hosts))
cumul_hosts <- cumsum(hosts)/max(cumsum(hosts))
plot(cumul_hosts, cumul_parasites, type= "l")
lines(cumul_hosts, cumul_parasites,col = 2, lwd = 2, type = "p")
legend("topleft", c('My calc', 'LC'), col = 1:2, lty = 1, box.col = 1)
```

and this fits the Lc calculation exactly.

[image: Lc and my calculation comparison]